# What's wrong with "sale of 100% of"

Tags: phrase-usage

Explain to me please what is wrong with the phrase "**sale of 100% of**"?

I googled this phrase and I obtained only 35 results.
I don't understand whether the phrase is incorrect in English or I do an incorrect search on the Internet.

The context is about the sale of a participating interest in a company (sale of 100% of the company, e.g. sale of 100% of Horns & Tails).

Comment: If I use Google and search for that phrase, with its quotes, I get "About 176,000,000 results (0.96 seconds)".

Comment: @Andrew Leach look at the last 5th page, not the 1st one. You will see only 35 results on the last page.

Comment: Just because something isn't preferred does not mean it's strictly wrong. However, we wouldn't normally qualify a complete sale with a fractional amount since it is unnecessary to use fractional math then. Instead, we would infer the information from the unqualified "The sale of the Horns & Tails Pub" and assume all of it was sold because it wasn't divided. Even when we need to specify that the entire company was sold, we would likely use an adjective indicating completeness instead, like "The sale of the whole company." Also, English speakers often dislike repetitiveness, like  in 'of x of'.

Comment: ... Surely this means that Google searches can't be used as sound evidence rather than 'there is something wrong with the string in question'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is making an unsubstantiated claim. It also fails to recognise that other examples including '100% of' may well be less usual choices than 'the whole of', 'all of' etc.

Comment: If I google "The porcupine has lost its way." I get zero results for the precise phrase in quotes.That doesn't mean that it is an incorrect sentence.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Okay. Thanks for the downvote. I don't live in an English speaking country and English is not my native language. Google is not a reliable source of information. How can I know what's wrong and what's right then?

Comment: The dictionaries don't provide such specific information either. And nice persons here are just waiting for any opportunity to close or to downvote a question.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth What a nice question "Me and Susie are going to dinner". Go and answer to this question, this is soooooo interesting.

Comment: The sister site, ELL, is specifically aimed at people who are in the situation you seem to be in. If you check at the Help Center here, you will see the ELU site aims.  // Andrew Leach has pointed out that Google is unreliable for frequencies of examples, so 'Explain to me please what is wrong with the phrase ...' is unwarranted. Tonepoet's reply is spot on. But I commend him, because he has not acceded to your 'You could make it an answer', the reason being, perhaps, that he considers as I do that the question as it stands is not suitable for ELU.

Answer (score 0):

In English, the active voice is preferred. Also, when it comes to 100% many speakers will prefer to say "completely, entirely" etc. Your sentence is not wrong, but is cumbersome to speak, and I think it could be better phrased as "Horn & Tails has been completely sold to..." or "The entirety of Hirn & Tails has been sold to..."

Comment: You're right on all counts, but...  "The active voice is preferred" is passive, as is "Horn & Tails has been sold" --!

Comment: Is the active voice really preferred in English, or is that one of those opinions masquerading as rules perpetuated by the likes of Strunk & White in defiance of actual common usage?

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly wrong, but it's easy to get lost in the repetition of "of," especially so close together.  You may find a wording that avoids this and easier to follow -- but it's not *that* confusing.  I'd leave it if it's important to emphasize the 100%.